# Using Custom Class in Reactive Spring Repository

Tags: spring, reactive

I am trying to define a custom class like:

```
public final class CustomFlux<T> extends Flux<T> {
}
```

And then define a JPA function like:

```
public interface TestReactiveRepository {

    CustomFlux<Test> findAllByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

But I am getting the following error, is what I am trying to do not possible?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen cannot be cast to class com.test.CustomFlux (reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen and com.test.CustomFlux are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I can't share my exact code so this is all generalized.

Comment: What would you like? Extending Flux object?

Comment: I am already extending the Flux object, but when I try to call findAllByFirstName("FirstName") I get the error provided, there doesn't seem to be a way to return the CustomFlux type.

Comment: There is `A extends B` and `C extends B`. You can `B b = new A()` but you can not `A a = new B()` and  `C c = new A()`. In code: `final class FluxUsingWhen<T, S> extends Flux<T> implements SourceProducer<T>`

Comment: Yes I get that, but what I don't get is why Reactive Spring is using FluxUsingWhen when executing the query instead of just Flux. Is it something I am doing wrong? Is it simply not possible to return CustomFlux from a repository? I do not seem to see anything else that shows Flux being extended, is it bad practice to extend Flux?

Comment: I never tried to decorate Flux on Java. But this idea is good because there may be repeated implementations you would like to use in the project. I use this extension, only in the Kotlin environment (which essentially means 1-8 lines of code) but haven't used it in Java yet. I would have to see how it could be done.